# How to insert data into some columns if they don't exist and update them if they do exists using mysql

Tags: mysql

For example
INSERT INTO tests(test1, test2,test3) values(10,20,15).
if these values exists already, update or overwrite it.

Comment: REPLACE INTO is what you probably looking for

Answer (score 0):

For the query you need a unique Key constraints, so that the update get processed.

```
 INSERT INTO tests(test1, test2,test3) values(10,20,15) 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test1 = VALUES(test1),test2 = VALUES(test2),test3 = VALUES(test3);
```

see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)